# Computer wakes from sleep

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp

I have a Macbook Pro 2015 with Retina Display running Windows 10.  I have noticed two peculiar sets of behavior.

1) I wrote myself a timestamp application that writes to a file every x minutes(only when a user is logged in) to show when I was logged in.  I leave around 4 everyday.  But when I get back the next day, the program always has a stamp for **5:55 pm.**

2) I usually put my computer to sleep right when I leave at 4 PM.  Several times though when I come in the next day around 7 am the fans are running on full and the machine is very hot.

It may be paranoia, but I don't the idea of my machine running some unknown process while I am not there.  The only solution I have currently is to shut it down completely every day when I leave.

Any thoughts on what could be happening?

Comment: Does it hibernate or something after a certain time? That would explain the 5:55. And check event logs for reason why it's waking up, or run `powercfg -lastwake`

Comment: windows 10 enjoys rebooting to install updates. Check if maybe it did that.

Answer (score 1):

Check which devices are configured to allow waking the computer using the following command (from an elevated *Administrator* command prompt):

```
powercfg -DEVICEQUERY wake_armed
```

The following command will trace energy for a minute or so, which may help to provide clues:

```
powercfg -energy
```

If you know the computer was sleeping, then it woke while you were away (so you find it awake), then use the following to query information on whatever woke it from the last sleep:

```
powercfg -LASTWAKE
```

From Device Manager you can configure devices to disallow waking (be sure to leave it allowed for things like keyboard and mouse, but you may want to disable for other devices, including network adapters).

From Start | Settings | System | Power and Sleep, Change the Plan settings for your configuration and then select to Change Advnaced Power Settings. From here scroll the list and ensure all these are configured to 'Allow the computer to sleep'.

Next check any scheduled tasks in your Task Scheduler to see if any are configured to Wake the Computer. It could be something like an Adobe update or some other scheduled task that is configured to wake the computer.

Also consider any streaming applications or video applications (uTorrent, VLC, etc.) that may prevent proper sleep. If in doubt, try stopping these sorts of applications (and their associated services) to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Next time this happens I will try this and will mark this as the correct answer if it helps me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: hibernate, put laptop in backpack, when I arrive home I can hear the fan running full blast, and the laptop is very hot. I found that the Bluetooth driver can turn the laptop back on. So this has worked for me: Device Manager, Bluetooth, Broadcom, rightclick, properties, Power Management, uncheck the ability to turn the power back on. Thanks to this thread and to https://discussions.apple.com/message/30365159

Since then, the issue has stopped - it's been a month

Comment: A couple of months later, I enabled Cortana for something. The problem came back - and did not show up with powercfg. 24 hours later, I disabled Cortana. Problem has not reoccurred since then